# Change the selection of a table view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm starting with iOS development and I want to implement the following behavior in a table view:
Element 1 of the list cant be selected and when other row is selected the previous element in the list becomes the selected one. I know is senseless, it is just as an exercise. By the way my code is:

```
-(NSIndexPath *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSUInteger row =[indexPath row];
if (row==0){
    return nil;
}
   return indexPath;
}
```

It works for avoiding the row 0 from being selected, now I need change the selected element to the previous when the row!=0. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableView has a method named [`selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/selectRowAtIndexPath%3aanimated%3ascrollPosition%3a) (documentation linked for you) where you can select a different row.

A couple caveats about this though:  you have to select a row via an NSIndexPath (not too hard to set up, once you get the hang of it) and your `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` may be called a second time when you programatically call `selectRowAtIndexPath` so you need to figure out a way to ignore that call while paying attention to the ones the user does with their finger.